# Linux (Ubuntu) Prevent User from Renaming Mounted Directory

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, mount

So, I have a FTP setup on Ubuntu.

They have access to these directories as home:

- /home/{user}
- /home/{user}

I have directories outside of home:

- /var/ftp/shared/legal
- /var/ftp/shared/finance

The above are mounted to the users home directory as:

- /home/{user}/legal
- /home/{user}/finance

My question is, how can I prevent the user from renaming their "legal | finance" directory in their home directory while being able to add directories and files? Would they even be able to do this by default?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can't. The ability of renaming files (or directories) within a directory depends on the permissions the user has over the parent directory, not the file (or directory) to be renamed. Given those subfolders are in the home directories, the users will always be able to rename those subdirectories.

Comment: Might be able to prevent this with some settings in vsftpd. But I havn't looked into it much. nothing would prevent them from renaming it if they had user / group write privs on the directory itself by logging into the OS of course.

Comment: @Jose, I was afraid of that. I will just make sure the users know not to rename the folder(s).